# how to set the new cookie without reloading the page

Tags: angular

I am using

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';
```

whenever the there is some authenticatin error I show the login popup and successfully authenticate the user and set the cookie.

But after setting the cookie, If I access any service it appends the old expired cookie not the new cookie..

```
public getAllBreakReasons = (): Observable<any> => {
    //console.log('from WorkObject Service')
    return this._http.get(`${this.breakReasonBaseUrl}/getAllBreakReasons?authToken=${Cookie.get('authToken')}`).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This is to not to disturb the user's page... This is for implementing session expires funcitonality.

Comment: can you post the code where you set the cookie?

Comment: however, you're using a package deprecated, maybe you can try to use other package like https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie.